# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE when using emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I know this has been answered a lot, but I have done everything that I've searched in Google, but nothing works.

The emulator always sets its internal memory to 200MB. I can't even install on external because it gives me error. I have also tried changing the .ini file and sets `-partition-size 1024` but it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: If possible, could you add any links that you've tried? We don't know "what" you have done. Also, if there is error, mention the detail on the question.

Comment: uninstall some apps from your emulator

Comment: Can you post your AVD configuration? Do you have HAXM enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better alternative to the official Android emulator.

Try using [Genymotion Android emulator](http://www.genymotion.com) instead.

Comment: actually I'm having problems with genymotion the link on the tutorial in them are not working